# What genre is the music from "A Monster in Paris"?

Tags: identify-this-genre, jazz, pop, similar-artists, funk

I absolutely love the music from ["A Monster in Paris"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Monster_in_Paris). I am having difficulty pinpointing the genre so I can find similar artists and music.

It seems like some kind of upbeat jazz/pop sound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not very good in genre naming, but it is close to what we call *Chanson Française* or *Variété*.

This is a typical style in France so I will suggest only songs in French (I don't have english suggestions in mind right now).

- [Debout sur le Zinc - Mieux que Rien](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DV5fLxQNEgU)
- [Renan Luce - La Lettre](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Vv5sDQ9aFU)
- [Les VRP - Léo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RsLW5xNYZeQ)

Check out those bands and related tracks and you will probably find something.

Comment: You sir have brought me great joy. Why is this not a genre elsewhere. It is amazing.

Comment: I believe those French bands belong to a genre named "nouvelle scène française", best known in English as [Nouvelle Chanson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nouvelle_Chanson)