# What genre would "Sin jedinac" and "Ljudmila" by Djordje Balasevic fall under?

Tags: identify-this-genre

Here are two songs by Djordje Balasevic, I like them and I'm trying to figure out what genre they belong to.

- [Sin jedinac](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TMD2s5SbHng)
- [Ljudmila](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OA5_8YjA4Is)

Answer (score 2):

[The artist is Serbian/Yugoslavian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%90or%C4%91e_Bala%C5%A1evi%C4%87).  I'm no expert in music from this part of the world, but it seems to have a Eastern European polka bassline combined with a french pop "[nouvelle chanson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nouvelle_Chanson)" style.

Compare the music linked in these questions and their answers:

- [What Genre is the music from "Monster in Paris"](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/3480/what-genre-is-the-music-from-monster-in-paris/4411#4411)
- [What is the style/genre of the non-English sections of Panic is Perfect's "Go Go Go"?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/5646/what-is-the-style-genre-of-the-non-english-sections-of-panic-is-perfects-go-go/5651#5651)
- [What is the genre of the Ievan Polkka?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/5563/what-is-the-genre-of-this-music/5565#5565)